# Get Version of Journey Builder in Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, databinding, api-version

Is it possible to get the version of Journey builder (inside Custom Activity) from which the execute method got triggered??
or Any other identifier to decide if its a new journey/ a version of same journey ??

My Payload was something like this,

```
{
  "name": "p_template2",
  "id": "08d00fa3-28eblahblah-blah",
  "key": "REST-1",
  "type": "REST",
  "arguments": {
    "executionMode": "{{Context.ExecutionMode}}",
    "definitionId": "{{Context.DefinitionId}}",
    "activityId": "{{Activity.Id}}",
    "contactKey": "{{Context.ContactKey}}",
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [
        {
          "subscriberKey": "{{Event.DEAudience-52a7466blah-blah82c108.contact_id}}",
          "token": "{{Event.DEAudience-52a7466d-7beblah-blah7a82c108.email_token}}",
          "tokenRequestId": "{{Event.DEAudience-52a7466d-blah-blah108.email_token}}",
          "SendKey": "SMS  Journey Mar 8",
          "message": "\nHi \nTake 20% off your order with code ☻\n"
        }
      ],
      "outArguments": [],
      "url": "https://blah-blah.azurewebsites.net/myjourneybuilder/execute",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "format": "json",
      "useJwt": true,
      "timeout": 60000
    },
    "testExecute": "",
    "startActivityKey": "{{Context.StartActivityKey}}",
    "definitionInstanceId": "{{Context.DefinitionInstanceId}}",
    "requestObjectId": "{{Context.RequestObjectId}}"
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "save": "",
    "testSave": "",
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://blah-blah.azurewebsites.net/myjourneybuilder/publish",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "testPublish": "",
    "unpublish": "",
    "stop": "",
    "testStop": "",
    "testUnpublish": "",
    "partnerActivityId": "",
    "validate": "",
    "testValidate": "",
    "outArgumentSchema": "",
    "executeSchema": ""
  },
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "https://blah-blah.azurewebsites.net/images/icon.png",
    "iconSmall": "https://blah-blah.azurewebsites.net/images/iconSmall.png",
    "category": "Customer Updates",
    "statsContactIcon": "",
    "original_iconSmall": "images/iconSmall.png",
    "original_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "isConfigured": true
  },
  "editable": true,
  "outcomes": [
    {
      "key": "1b99391e-5bblah-blah1c2bab8286",
      "next": "WAITBYDURATION-2",
      "arguments": {},
      "metaData": {
        "invalid": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": null
}
```

I added static version in config.json , thought to give a try !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include the data binding key `{{Context.VersionNumber}}` as an inArgument.